# How to show answers which are more than 1 decimal point long in C++

Tags: c++, decimal

My C++ program has an division operation which goes like this after the using namespace and stuff.

```
cout<<"Please type the data";

cin>> a;

z = a/4;

cout<<"The answer is"<< z;
```

The program gives accurate numbers if I type a number which is divisible like

ex. a=8, z=4

But when comes to numbers that are not directly divisible by 4 it shows the result as shown

a=54

b=13    // the real answer is 13.5

It ignores the numbers before the decimal point.
How can I include all the numbers before the decimal points in my result (or at least till 4 decimal places,)?

Please help.

Comment: The variables `a` and `z` in your example, what types are they? If they are `float` it should work automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you are defining a and z as type int. Instead define them as double and your problem will be solved.

```
    double a, z;

cout<<"Please type the data";

cin>> a;

z = a/4;

cout<<"The answer is"<< z;
```

Answer (score 2):

use an appropriate type:

```
double z = 0.;

z = 54/4.;

std::cout << z << std::endl;
```

NOTE: `4.` rather than `4`, else the above division will simply be an integer division rather than a floating point division.

You can also ensure that a floating point division happens by accepting a `double`/`float` from the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
cout<<"The answer is"<< setprecision(2) << z;
```